# How to refactor this component to avoid repetition?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to refactor this component to avoid repetition. There are 5 levels of `depth`, `0` - `4` which is a prop. Depending on depth's value, I want to change the css `className` as you can see. Up until now I had copies of the whole code for each level of depth. I also want to change whether `preview` is shown based on whether the `preview` prop is undefined or not. Im stumped in terms of the best approach! Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

```
function Node({ type, name, depth, isEmptyFolder, preview, extension, handleClick }) {

  const classes = useStyles();
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);

  function handlePopoverOpen(event) {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  }

  function handlePopoverClose() {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  }

  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);

  const renderNode = () => {
    if (depth === 0 && type === 'folder') {
      return (
        <div className="depth0" onClick={() => handleClick(type, depth, preview, isEmptyFolder)} >
          <FolderOpen style={{ fontSize: 50 }} />
          <div>
          {name}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
    if (depth === 0 && type === 'file') {
      return (
        <div className="depth0" onClick={() => handleClick(type, depth, preview, isEmptyFolder)}>
          <FileCopy style={{ fontSize: 50 }} />
          <Typography
            aria-owns={open ? 'mouse-over-popover' : undefined}
            aria-haspopup="true"
            onMouseEnter={handlePopoverOpen}
            onMouseLeave={handlePopoverClose}
          >
            {name + extension} | Preview
        </Typography>
          <Popover
            id="mouse-over-popover"
            className={classes.popover}
            classes={{
              paper: classes.paper,
            }}
            open={open}
            anchorEl={anchorEl}
            anchorOrigin={{
              vertical: 'bottom',
              horizontal: 'left',
            }}
            transformOrigin={{
              vertical: 'top',
              horizontal: 'left',
            }}
            onClose={handlePopoverClose}
            disableRestoreFocus
          >
            <Typography>{preview}</Typography>
          </Popover>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      {renderNode()}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: className = {"depth" + depth} for changing classname based on depth.

Comment: {preview === undefined ? <div>preview</div> : null}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string literals to use the depth parameter inside the string

```
className={`depth${depth}`}
```

This will result in "depth0" for depth=0 and also "depth4" for depth=4

For the preview issue you can use conditional rendering

```
{preview && (
   <Typography>{preview}</Typography>
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you don't need to repeat the `<div className="depth0"....` part.

```
function Node({ type, name, depth, isEmptyFolder, preview, extension, handleClick }) {

  const classes = useStyles();
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);

  function handlePopoverOpen(event) {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  }

  function handlePopoverClose() {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  }

  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);

  const renderNode = () => {
    let content;
    if (depth === 0 && type === 'folder') {
      content = (
        <>
          <FolderOpen style={{ fontSize: 50 }} />
          <div>
          {name}
          </div>
        </>
      );
    }
    if (depth === 0 && type === 'file') {
      content = (
        <>
          <FileCopy style={{ fontSize: 50 }} />
          <Typography
            aria-owns={open ? 'mouse-over-popover' : undefined}
            aria-haspopup="true"
            onMouseEnter={handlePopoverOpen}
            onMouseLeave={handlePopoverClose}
          >
            {name + extension} | Preview
        </Typography>
          <Popover
            id="mouse-over-popover"
            className={classes.popover}
            classes={{
              paper: classes.paper,
            }}
            open={open}
            anchorEl={anchorEl}
            anchorOrigin={{
              vertical: 'bottom',
              horizontal: 'left',
            }}
            transformOrigin={{
              vertical: 'top',
              horizontal: 'left',
            }}
            onClose={handlePopoverClose}
            disableRestoreFocus
          >
            <Typography>{preview}</Typography>
          </Popover>
        </>
      );
    }
    return (
      <div className="depth0" onClick={() => handleClick(type, depth, preview, isEmptyFolder)} >
        {content}
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      {renderNode()}
    </>
  );
}
```